# AngularJS filter in React Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm totally new to **ReactJS**, but I love its awesome performance over AngularJS. My question is, in AngularJS we use filters in the view templates before rendering the expression or model, how we can achieve that in ReactJS. Now I'm trying to replace few view parts as React Components(still it is in AngularJS).

For example, now my below angular code works fine to render a emoticon in p tag,

```
<div ng-init='{messageWithAngularEmoji = "This is a :smile:"}'>

     <p ng-bind="{messageWithAngularEmoji | emoji | to_trusted }"></p>

</div>
```

In the above example you can see I had used two filters: **emoji** and **to_trusted**. How can I achieve this in ReactJS ?

Note: I can't rewrite those filters in React.

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, so I can't give you exact code example but in ReactJS you can write just plain JS code, so find out how Angular changes those filters into function exeuction. Probably in the end it will look as simple as: `<p>{emoji(messageWithAngularEmoji)}</p>`.

Comment: The angular code should not have any `{`, `}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little search I found the way to retrieve angular filter outside of angular, so in your case this should do a trick:

```
render: function() {
    var injector = angular.element("div[ng-controller]").injector(); 
    var emoji = injector.get('emojiFilter'); 
    var message = 'This is a :smile:';
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{emoji(message)}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In angular a filter is just a very contrived way to call a function.

```
module.filter('emoji', function(){
  return function(x){
    /* stuff */
  };
});
```

Becomes

```
function emoji(x){
    /* stuff */
};
```

React is just JavaScript, so you define functions and you use them.

```
<p>{to_trusted(emoji(messageWithAngularEmoji))}</p>
```

You probably don't need to_trusted because that's likely referring to SCE, which is part of angular.

Comment: I liked the info that there is no requirement for SCE here +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

This question has already been answered correctly.  I want to provide a different perspective using ES6 for any future readers like myself.

Writing a currency filter using ReactJS

**currency.js**

```
export default function(value, decimalPosition = 2) {
    return '$' + value
        .toFixed(decimalPosition)
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,')
}
```

**component.js**

```
export default function FundsAmount() {
    let amount = 2345.43

    return (
        <span>{ currency(amount) }</span>
    )
}
```

This will output:

```
$2,345.43
```

Comment: awesome !, i was really about to change back to angular after frustration from the amount of components and boilerplate code i have to write to achieve simple filtering or pagination in react. using this approach made my day !